# Concurrent Connections in Okhttp

Tags: android, concurrency, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using okhttp in android app. I am facing a very weird issue while making multiple calls in parallel. If I make multiple calls at once when the app just started. Instead of all the calls going in parallel some times the second call will start with delay. However if I keep increase the number of calls. Most of the call will start concurrently and few calls will start with delay.

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
            delay(5000)
            val jobs= (0 until 2).map {
               async { homeRemoteDataSource.getEnums() }
            }
            jobs.awaitAll()
        }
```

Okhttp client

```
val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        client.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        client.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        client.addInterceptor(authorization)
        client.addInterceptor(contentType)
        client.dispatcher(Dispatcher().apply {
            maxRequests = 100
            maxRequestsPerHost = 100
        })
        client.connectionPool(ConnectionPool(maxIdleConnections = 10, keepAliveDuration = 5,TimeUnit.MINUTES))
        client.build()
```

[image: Only two calls]
[image: Only two calls]
[image: Same result with 10 calls]
[image: Same result with 10 calls]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
       .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       .addInterceptor(authorization)
       .addInterceptor(contentType)
       .dispatcher(Dispatcher().apply {
            maxRequests = 100
            maxRequestsPerHost = 100
        })
       .connectionPool(ConnectionPool(maxIdleConnections = 10, keepAliveDuration = 5,TimeUnit.MINUTES))
       .build()
```

Comment: Hey I think you just gave me my old code.

Comment: I didn’t! In particular the result of build() is not ignored.

Comment: Oh my bad. however in my actual code. I was only using it after calling build. Forgot to post here.